# Save file from javascript and set custom name

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I wonder is there a way to override save file dialogue, while saving file in javascript.

I have a file (html or text or image) that is saved in localstorage. I would like to download it, but to set its download name to whatever I need. Right now it works, but it defaults to download (name) and file type (all).

This is the code that allows me to selectively pick whatever I need from local storage, but as I described above I have issue with name. I can't use server for this, as this is standalone Backbone project.

```
var base64 = window.btoa(this.model.get("filecontent")),   
fileDownLoadInformation;

fileDownLoadInformation = "<a href='data:application/octet-stream;base64," + base64 + "'" +   
">Download</a>"

//All file type have these options
extraOptions = "<div>" + fileDownLoadInformation + "</div>";

//etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create downloadable file from JavaScript I think you could use [Blob API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). See at HTML and you'll find "download" attribute on link, that will be the filename. Then you just need to change the content source from textarea to localStorage. I hope it could help you. Cheers.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="content">woo hoo! I'm going to be in a file!</textarea>
<p><a href="#" id="link" download="whatever.txt">download me</a></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#content').on('change', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    //this is OK for our example code but should be throttled in production
    var _downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([$this.val()] , {type:'text/plain'}));

    $('#link').attr('href', _downloadUrl);
}).change();
```